# Why does MSVC push and pop from the stack so much unlike Clang does

Tags: c++, visual-studio, optimization, clang, compiler-optimization

Using Godbolt's latest MSVC x64 compiler with /Ox (see link) generates far more assembly than I'd expect:

https://godbolt.org/z/ot5rYK

I'd expect both Fixed::Create, Fixed::Fixed and FixedPrimitive::FixedPrimitive to be inlined into the main function.

This can be proven by Clang 9.0's output using -O3 which is exactly what I'd expect.  MSVC doesn't seem to optimise away the function calls and instead pushes and pops the arguments all the way through.  Is there a command line argument I can use to make MSVC's output look a lot more like Clang's output?

As you should be able to see I've tried omitting frame pointers by using /Oy.

Infact here's my MSVC command line options:

```
/GS- /W3 /Gy- /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /Ox /Zc:inline /fp:fast /Oi /errorReport:prompt /GF /WX- /Zc:forScope /arch:AVX2 /Gv /Oy /Oi /MD /std:c++latest /FC /EHsc /nologo /Ot /diagnostics:column
```

This is the example code, excuse the global it is there to stop Clang optimising this code to nothing!  I use naked new because usually I overload the new operator to allocate out of a specific memory pool which make_unique doesn't allow.

```
typedef unsigned int u32;

struct FixedPrimitive
{
    FixedPrimitive(u32 rgba, u32 emissive, u32 transform_view, u32 id)
     :  m_colour(rgba),
        m_emissive(emissive),
        m_transform_view(transform_view),
        m_id(id)
    {}

    u32                 m_colour            = 0;
    u32                 m_emissive          = 0;
    u32                 m_transform_view    = 0;
    u32                 m_id                = 0;
};

struct Fixed
{
    static std::unique_ptr<Fixed> Create(u32 rgba, u32 emissive, u32 transform_view, u32 id);

    Fixed(const FixedPrimitive& primitive)
     :  m_primitive(primitive)
    {}

    FixedPrimitive m_primitive;
};

inline std::unique_ptr<Fixed> Fixed::Create(u32 rgba, u32 emissive, u32 transform_view, u32 id)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Fixed> fixedQuad    = std::unique_ptr<Fixed>( new Fixed(FixedPrimitive(rgba, emissive, transform_view, id)) );

    return fixedQuad;
}

std::unique_ptr<Fixed> g_fixed;

int main()
{
    g_fixed = Fixed::Create(10, 20, 30, 40);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And where exactly do you see the call you expect to inlined ? when I look at the main function theres no call there so it looks inlined to me. -please note assembly is overall different in compiler explorer for MSVC (basicly I think you may a see a lot of things being genereated that is later removed by the linker)

Comment: The actual portion of the code which is being used is basically the same. The MSVC does not remove the functions at this point. As darune mentioned, this is probably done at link time instead.

Comment: @darune Added all the functions I'd expect to see inlined under MSVC 19.22 which Clang 9.0 does inline.  So we think the linker is going to optimise all this code?  Seems a bit of a strange place to do that because all these functions are in the same compilation unit.  I could understand whole program optimisation /GL doing this sort of thing especially if it was across compilation units.  If true no wonder MSVC has terrible link times on top of already terrible compile times.

Comment: @user176168 please point out where you see the offending call - that the functions are being genereated is not the same as they are not being inlined. Whole program optimization is related but hasn't anything to do with this - what the linker does is remove those 'dead functions' and hasn't anything to do with whole program optimization. Like I said, to me it looks fine and that everything was inlined in the main function.

Comment: @darune Yes apologies I see what you mean there is no call to the those functions inside main and that is all dead assembly.  I just had seen the call (to the new operator) and stupidly just assumed that was the call to the rest of the assembly.  I'm brand new to using Compiler Explorer and wasn't expecting to see dead assembly like this, I was expecting to see output similar to Clang's.

Comment: @darune having said that I still see MSVC pushing all the args onto the stack and uses a movups to move them into the vector registers whereas Clang uses a single movaps to do the same thing.

Comment: @user176168 it would be easier to help if you would make  a minimal example (if possible) - or point to exactly the issue you see. maybe you should just close this one and make a new question ?

Comment: Also, please note that MSVC takes some different decisions in optimization sometimes than gcc/clang usual does. One thing is that more often it prefers smaller code instead of inlining - thus using less cpu cache, this is tradeoff, and can be overridden with the extension __forceinline

Comment: [Report it to Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=8). They might actually solve it.